# How to access Array List in another file in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a `constant.kt` file in my android project and it have a array list like this.

```
fun getQuestions(): ArrayList<Questions> {
    val questionsList = ArrayList<Questions>()
    val que1 = Questions(
                1, "What country does this flag belong to?",
                R.drawable.ic_flag_of_argentina,
                "Argentina", "Australia",
                "Armenia", "Austria", 1
        )
    return questionsList
```

Now I want to access this questionList in another android activity. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your getQuestions method in a object:

```
object Questions {
  fun getQuestions(): ArrayList<Questions> {
    val questionsList = ArrayList<Questions>()
    val que1 = Questions(
            1, "What country does this flag belong to?",
            R.drawable.ic_flag_of_argentina,
            "Argentina", "Australia",
            "Armenia", "Austria", 1
    )
    return questionsList
  }
}
```

And now you can use Questions.getQuestions() in every other File (assuming you import the Questions object accordingly)